# How to run a Symfony console command automatically when certain files change

Tags: php, symfony, console

Anyone have any idea how to automatically run a Symfony console command whenever any files matching a specified pattern changes? Similar to how you can watch for file changes in other automated task runners like gulp and grunt?

Comment: If you already use grunt, then you can use grunt watch combined with one of available modules which let you run shell commands.

Comment: @JakubMatczak I don't use grunt or gulp. Just sighted them as examples of tools that do what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You could write another console command that works as watch-daemon checking for the file and then running the other one as a [Process](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html).

There are also existing tools that you can use for monitoring that allow to trigger a command. One example I know is [monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/) and the [existence check](https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#EXISTENCE-TESTS).

Alternatively you can write your own shell script that uses a combination of `watch` and `grep`/`awk` that runs continuously and triggers the action.

I would go for monit as it seems the most hassle free and can be used for other monitoring tasks as well that are common, e.g. restart a service when it becomes unresponsive.